# Azure Streaming Analytics custom dlls

Tags: c#, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have a c# code which processes real time data and returns some calculations. How can I deploy this c# dll to azure stream analytics?
Any help, recommendations or documents would be very appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the stream analytics now doesn't support calling the function from the C# dlls. I suggest could try to use the [JavaScript user-defined functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions).

> Azure Stream Analytics supports user-defined functions written in JavaScript. With the rich set of String, RegExp, Math, Array, and Date methods that JavaScript provides, complex data transformations with Stream Analytics jobs become easier to create.

Besides, I suggest you could send a feedback at this [site](https://feedback.azure.com/) to suggest azure team to include this feature.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your answer. Instead of using dll, is there a way to use native c# code which does multiple calculations in azure stream analytics?

Comment: As far as I know, we could only use JavaScript user-defined functions. We couldn't use C# codes.